# vba copy discontinuous range cells

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I'm trying to copy discontinuous range cells to another sheet.

- my first range is on sheet Dati, range A3:G300
- sencond range is on sheet Dati, range AA3:AA300
- Third range is on sheet Dati, range AC3:AC300
- my destination is on sheet Calcolo, range A3:I300
- I want to use union(range1, range2, range3) to create a new range and move/copy it on range A3:I300 of Calcolo sheet

My code is the following but there's a problem because on destination sheet "Calcolo" from A3 to G300 data are correct and from H3 to I300 my data are not considered with #N/D values.

```
Sub copia()

Dim SelectA As Range
Dim SelectB As Range
Dim SelectC As Range
Dim UnionABC As Range
Dim RangeInc As Range

Set SelectA = Sheets("Dati").Range("A3:G300")
Set SelectB = Sheets("Dati").Range("AA3:AA300")
Set SelectC = Sheets("Dati").Range("AC3:AC300")
Set UnionABC = Union(SelectA, SelectB, SelectC)
Set RangeInc = Sheets("Calcolo").Range("A3:I300")

RangeInc = UnionABC.Value

End Sub
```

Any help to find errors or any idea to recode it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the clipboard and use direct value transfer with an intermediary variant array.

```
sub copia2()

    dim arr as variant, tmp as variant, i as long

    with workSheets("Dati")
        arr = .Range("A3:G300").value

        'collect AA
        tmp = .Range("AA3:AA300").value
        'make room for AA
        redim preserve arr(lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1), _
                           lbound(arr, 2) to ubound(arr, 2) + 1)
        'transfer AA
        for i = lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, ubound(arr, 2)) = tmp(i, 1)
        next i

        'collect AC
        tmp = .Range("AC3:AC300").value
        'make room for AC
        redim preserve arr(lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1), _
                           lbound(arr, 2) to ubound(arr, 2) + 1)
        'transfer AC
        for i = lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, ubound(arr, 2)) = tmp(i, 1)
        next i

    end with

    with workSheets("Calcolo")

       'transfer values to destination
        .Range("A3").resize(ubound(arr, 1), ubound(arr, 2)) = arr

    end with

end sub
```

Comment: This works great, your code is a little bit complicated for me, but I have great code to study on! thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there with your code.

Where you copy to the sheet Calcolo, replace that part of your code

```
RangeInc = UnionABC.Value
```

With the following:

```
UnionABC.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Calcolo").Range(RangeInc.Address)
```

Comment: a) Isn't `...Range(RangeInc.Address)` just a redundant `...RangeInc` if rangeinc has already been Set to Sheets("Calcolo").Range("A3:I300")? b) I find that using the single top-left cell of a destination is the least problematic.

Comment: a) It definitely is... actually the whole `Set RangeInc = Sheets("Calcolo").Range("A3:I300")` could be removed and you can only use -> `UnionABC.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Calcolo").Range("A3:I300")`, which I would personally prefer. b) I agree with you :). Since I didn't mention that `RangeInc` would be useless if you use `.Range("A3:I300")`, I wanted to use the `RangeInc` variable...